# Getting zeroPaddedFilemode error while loading a repository from Bitbucket to Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I am facing issues while loading a repository from Bitbucket to Gerrit.

Error:

> fatal: Unpack error, check server log error: remote unpack failed:
>   error zeroPaddedFilemode: object
>   087fbb748f50af6eac2248a445d25d666cc92c78: mode starts with '0' error:
>   failed to push some refs to
>   'ssh://mythravarun.nr@mygerrit.server.com:29418/myproject'

Steps I am trying:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin "ssh://mythravarun.nr@mygerrit.server.com:29418/myproject"
git checkout master
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories --no-edit origin master
git push "ssh://mythravarun.nr@mygerrit.server.com:29418/myproject" --all
```

git fsck give a lot of warnings as below:

> Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done. warning in tree
>   087fbb748f50af6eac2248a445d25d666cc92c78: zeroPaddedFilemode: contains
>   zero-padded file modes warning in tree
>   122502d6614382bf35a0d4d9d1215761eb92e0c3: zeroPaddedFilemode: contains
>   zero-padded file modes

What is the workaround for this? I need to load repository with all history and branches. I am using the latest version of Gerrit btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the remote repository in the Gerrit server, you could try to execute the following command on the server:

```
git config receive.fsck.zeroPaddedFilemode warn
```

After that Git should just warn about zero-padded file modes but not reject them.

Comment: I tried that, post executing above command, I see below change in the config file

[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
        logallrefupdates = true
[receive "fsck"]
        zeroPaddedFilemode = warn

However, the error remains same

Comment: @MythraVarun: that should work, but note that you *must* run this `git config` command on the *server* (the machine to which the push is going), not on the client.